# Reduce size of DLL created directly with GCC

Tags: gcc, dll, size, reduce

Hi1 I just created a DLL with GCC. It only contains this simple function:

```
extern "C" {
    char* Message() {
        return (char*)"Cool";
    }
}
```

The resulted file's size is 42 Kb and I don't understand why is it so big, when a simple executable that creates and shows a GUI window only weights 8 Kb. Is there a way of reducing the size of the shared library? Why is it so big? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

If I create the same file with Code::Blocks, it only has 24 Kb. I wonder what way does CB create it in order to achieve that size?

**UPDATE**

It matters because I want to know that my library doesn't contain unnecessary code. My GCC command to create the DLL is:

```
gcc -c Source/MyLib.cpp -s -Os -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -o MyLib.o
ar  rcs libMylib.a MyLib.o
gcc -shared -o MyLib.dll MyLib.o
```

Comment: Why does it matter to you? And what options to `gcc`  have you given (`gcc -Wall -O3` ?)

Comment: Why don't you compile with `gcc -fPIC -shared -Os Source/MyLib.cpp -o MyLib.dll` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Yet, the same size.

Comment: Moreover, the -fPIC is ignored on my x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-s` to the linking state (`gcc -s -shared -o MyLib.dll MyLib.o`)

Comment: You are the boss. From 42Kb to 8Kb. Thanks to everyone!